# Change date format using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

How to change the date format using angularjs, 
    I did try to this bellow format

```
<td><% company.pivot.joined_date  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a' %></td>
```

and also try this format.but not changing this 2015-07-28 10:03:14 ,please help me.

```
<td ng-bind="company.pivot.joined_date | date:'MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a'"></td>
```

Comment: I would suggest looking if there are any uncaught exceptions in the code. Your first attempt should work, the second one not so much .. (First one assuming you have proper handles)

Answer (score 1):

**create this filter**

```
filters.filter('dateFormat', function ($filter) {
return function (input) {
    if (input == null) {
        return '';
    }

    //var date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'mediumDate');
    var date = $filter('date')(moment(input).toDate(), 'mediumDate');

    return date;
}
```

});

**then**

```
<td>{{company.pivot.joined_date.date | dateFormat}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Is there any reason why you are not using handles?

```
<td>{{ company.pivot.joined_date| date: 'MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a'}}</td>
```

Comment: Displaying date, but not changing date format to Mar-09-2015, 03:42 pm.  .

Comment: I am confused now... so, if you try <h5>{{ date | date: 'MMM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a'}}</h5>, does it not work?

Comment: That is working fine ,but this is not working.<td><% company.pivot.joined_date  | date:'MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a' %></td>

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using http://momentjs.com/ library for datetime purposes

Comment: This is a link only answer, can you elaborate to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in your input date, it is not in correct format as angularJs required

try this it works

```
<td><% new Date() | date:'MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a' %></td>
```

It simply means problem in input date format.

See here in [Date filter in AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)